# Is this site the most appropriate to ask questions about distributed algorithms?

Tags: feature-request, questions, asking-questions

For example, suppose I have a doubt regarding how Paxos works or about the definition of FIFO broadcasts. Is this website the most suited for asking this kind of questions?

For example, would [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15131730/3924118) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47869136/3924118) questions have been (more) appropriately asked on this CS website? If not, which is the most appropriate SE website to ask this kind of questions?

Comment: Thanks for asking!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Algorithms* are generally on-topic; implementing them is a gray area since *programming* questions are offtopic.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15131730/539599) would certainly be welcome on our site.

Note that we have a tag [distributed-systems] with many questions on Paxos already.